# Fetching detached entity again

Tags: jpa

I always thought that detached entities are just not managed by the manager anymore and any update won't be synchronized to a database.

But here a snippet I currently have in a code:

```
Car car1 = carRepository.findById(1L).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("(1) Cannot find car with ID 1"));
em.detach(car1);
Car car2 = carRepository.findById(1L).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("(2) Cannot find car with ID 1"));
```

After detaching the entity I am trying to load it again from database but it is not found! Is there any reason why? Or can anyone explain to me?

Thank you

Comment: Well, this shouldn't be happening. Could you give us some broader context?

Comment: Oh god, when I was editing the question I found the bug. Car was a newly created entity at few methods earlier. But it was not flushed to database. So after detaching, entity is not in db or cache, so it is not returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So problem was with detaching not synchronized entity to a database. Calling flush() before detaching it works now as expected and findById return result as usual.